# asp.net external JavaScript file doesn't find Control.ClientID

Tags: asp.net, javascript, clientid

On load I'm both calling a JavaScript setTimeout() function that will hide a .NET Panel control, and hiding it in the code behind on first load.  Clicking the save button will set the Panel to visible then reload the page at which point a setTimeout() function is called... so basically you click save, and see a panel with "Details Saved" for three seconds, at which point it disappears.

The problem is the external JavaScript file can't find _pDivAlert.ClientID (I've debugged and it returns null).  It only works when the code is in a  tag in the .aspx page.  Any suggestions as to how I can either pass the client ID to the HideControl() function or find the ClientID from the external JS file?

Here's my code, any suggestions?

```
<script language="javascript" src="Forms.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<body onload="ToggleAlert()">
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">
    //alert the user that the details were saved
    function HideControl() {
        var control = document.getElementById('<%=_pDivAlert.ClientID %>');
        if(control != null)
            control.style.display = 'none';
    }
    function ToggleAlert() {
        setTimeout("HideControl()", 3000);
    }
</script>
```

I've also tried sending the ClientID within the ToggleAlert() call, but that didn't work:

```
<body onload="ToggleAlert('<%=_pDivAlert.ClientID %>')">
```

External JS:

```
function HideControl(_c) {
var control = _c;
if (control != null)
    control.style.display = 'none';
}
function ToggleAlert(_c) {
    setTimeout("HideControl(_c)", 3000);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you show your markup with the panel and the codebehind where you hide it?

there's a difference between setting the `Visible` property to false and setting the style `display` attribute to none- the first will not render the element at all, meaning there isn't anything rendered with the id you're looking for.

edit: it's probably because of the way you're calling `HideControl` in the timeout- this should be a function instead of a string.

try doing

```
function ToggleAlert(_c) {
    setTimeout( 
        function () { 
            HideControl(_c); 
        }, 3000);
}
```

just for clarity, when you pass a string to `setTimeout`, it's evaluated and then run. the code chunk that eval produces will run in a different scope than your `ToggleAlert` method, and so `_c` won't be available at that time.

edit: you also need to actually get a reference to the control. you're passing the id string to `ToggleAlert`, which relays it to `HideControl`, which is expecting an object not a string.

```
function HideControl(_c) { // _c is the id of the element
    var control = document.getElementById(_c);
    if (control != null)
        control.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I made HideControl() a function, and now I'm seeing the control ID in the external JS.  But now when debugging I see that "style" in "control.style.display = 'none'" is "undefined."